# pycocotools - "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required" although installed

Tags: python, c++, visual-studio, tensorflow, visual-c++

I want to install the TensorFlow object detection API, for that, I need the pycocotools package, which is reliant on Visual Studio C++ Build Tools v14 or higher.

I have both tried to install the full Visual Studio 2022, as well as the Visual Studio build tools 2019 separately. No matter what I do, this is my error message:

```
Building wheel for pycocotools (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\linus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qcu6kn44\\pycocotools_48badac11907450f8dc23c6ec17df5de\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\linus\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-qcu6kn44\\pycocotools_48badac11907450f8dc23c6ec17df5de\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-d2xbzptl'
       cwd: C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcu6kn44\pycocotools_48badac11907450f8dc23c6ec17df5de\
  Complete output (16 lines):
  running bdist_wheel
  running build
  running build_py
  creating build
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9
  creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\coco.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\cocoeval.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\mask.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  copying pycocotools\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.9\pycocotools
  running build_ext
  cythoning pycocotools/_mask.pyx to pycocotools\_mask.c
  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\Cython\Compiler\Main.py:369: FutureWarning: Cython directive 'language_level' not set, using 2 for now (Py2). This will change in a later release! File: C:\Users\linus\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-qcu6kn44\pycocotools_48badac11907450f8dc23c6ec17df5de\pycocotools\_mask.pyx
    tree = Parsing.p_module(s, pxd, full_module_name)
  building 'pycocotools._mask' extension
  error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycocotools
```

I am on a Windows 11 machine with Anaconda3 2021.11 (Python 3.9.7 64-bit) installed.

My installation details inside Visual Studio installer look like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LncJa.png).

Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing MSBuild. You can add it from visual studio installer.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZ9sn.png) is what I have installed and `pycocotools` installed fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't help... I still get the same error message